# Share content on LinkedIn for both android and ios using react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, linkedin-api

I have an app built in react-native in which I have to share these data to LinkedIn

```
const options = {
            title: 'Share via',
            message: 'some message',
            image:'images need to be shared' //may be multiple images
            }
```

I tried so many ways but not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

your question need some details to be added, what are the permissions you have, usually such thing as you described can be done using the UgcPost Api or Share Api
you can fine more about this in the documentation 
[Ugc Post Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api)